# Intellij 14 + lombok: @Slf4j Cannot find symbol log

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14, lombok

Intellij doesn't recognize @SLF4J annotation. I have the following error:

```
Error:(105, 9) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   variable log
location: class com.xxxxx.SdsConfig
```

knowing that I have already Enable annotation processing (Settings -> Compiler -> Annotation Processors)

I use java 8 compiler.

Comment: If you are Maven this may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/59090028/4057038

Answer (score 5):

Use lombok plugin for Intellij:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317

This will highlight everything correctly and allow you to use auto completion for generated methods.

Note that some features (like @val) are supported in Intellij 14.1 and newer.

Answer (score 2):

In Intellij version 2016, 2017, the enabling of

```
Preferences -> Compiler -> Annotation Processors
```

did not work for me.

The following additional checkbox did help:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when I upgraded to IntelliJ 2016.

I already had the Lombok plugin installed and Annotation Processors enabled.

I had to download a Lombok plugin from https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok-plugin (0.15.16, as the most recent 0.15.17.2 wasn't compatible), then install it as a plugin to upgrade the installed Lombok plugin, then restart IntelliJ