# java: log cannot be resolved

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

i meet a problem 
I use

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.1 
Build #IU-173.3942.27, built on December 11, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_111-b14 amd64
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
Windows 7 6.1
```

> Error:(16, 10) java: log cannot be resolved

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.junit.Test;


@Slf4j
public class LogTest {

    @Test
    public void testSlf4j(){
         log.info("测试 lombok slf4j logback");
    }

}
```

i had config 
Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Annotation Enable annotation processing

Settings -> Other Settings -> Lombok

```
    <!-- SLF4J -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Logback -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.20</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Could you please attachscreenshot with your Annotation Processor settings? Have you tried to run "File | Invalidate Caches" and "Refresh" from maven tool window?

Comment: where did to define the "log" variable

Comment: For Intellij + Maven, try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59090028/4057038

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue. A simple maven update helped me. You can try the following from command line:

```
mvn clean install -U
```

and then run your application

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have to install [Lombok Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok-plugin) so that IDEA would know what does that annotation means.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to making sure you have the [Lombok Plugin](https://projectlombok.org/setup/intellij) installed you also need [annotation processing](https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-ide#intellij-apt) enabled.

After that I started to get this error and I needed to do a 'Build > Rebuild Project' to shake it off.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, in my case, the compiler configuration was wrong because the Ajc compiler was selected, so I change it to Javac instead.

Config path:

> File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Java
> Compiler

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a `lombok.config` file that renames to `log` variable to something else using `lombok.log.fieldName = xxx`?

Comment: And where should this configuration be set? It is not explained very well in the docs

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to @Slf4j and may be you are using any latest version of project lombok (1.18.x)+
try to install the earlier versions like 1.16.x which supports @Slf4j.

And then restart eclipse and rebuilt the project.

Answer (score 0):

1. Exit from the IDE.
2. **C:\Users{pcname}.m2\repository\org\projectlombok**    In this location delete all files.
3. Download Lombok jar from https://projectlombok.org/download , and start IDE.
4. Specify your IDE path like this..
   [Image to specify ide path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSJb1.png)
5. Start your IDE.

Comment: When I looked at the image, it felt more like Eclipse. The question specifically states the person is using Intellij.

Answer (score -1):

1.Go to https://projectlombok.org/
2.Download JAR file.
3.Run JAR file. Usually double-clicking JAR file is enough.
4.In the Lombok installation screen, make sure that your Spring Tool Suite instance is listed.
5.Click Install/Update, then Quit Installer.
6.Open Spring Tool Suite, go to About Spring Tool Suite. The large area that contains the version number should have the Lombok version listed at the bottom. You might have to scroll, even though there is no scroll bar.

All the Best.