# Lombok error has occurred when junit running

Tags: junit, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

It works in spring boot or normal projects
but it didn't work when junit running

I saw many many solutions about lombok
but, didn't work

for example

1. install lombok plugin in intellij
2. Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Annotation Processors -> Enable annotation processing check!

```java
import lombok.extern.java.Log;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Tag;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

@Tag("fast")
@Log
public class MainTest {

    @BeforeAll
    static void setup() {
        log.info("@BeforeAll - executes once before all test methods in this class");
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void init() {
        log.info("@BeforeEach - executes before each test method in this class");
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("My first junit 5 test")
    void additionTest() {
        assertEquals(1+1, 1);
    }
}
```

```
error: package lombok.extern.java does not exist
error: cannot find symbol @Log
```

Comment: Not sure, but it can be because of the scope of your dependency. What's the scope of Lombok dependency?

Comment: @MensurQulami I set compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8' so I chaged it like  implementation 'org.~~' but it didn't work as well

Comment: comes out this sentence "No tests found for given includes: [ com.~~~ ....](filter.includeTestsmatching)"

Comment: So, did it solve the error while producing that message?

Comment: No, whether it is a correct test or not comes out the upper sentence

Comment: Probably, you've seen this thread, but have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56856661/9985287) ?

Comment: although I tried this, it didn't work :(
I think junit 5 is the problem in this project 
I have to stick to it