# Building with Cucumber v6 and Lombok's @Slf4j: Cannot find symbol log

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber, slf4j, lombok

After update from cucumber v 4.8.0 to 6.8.0, my project fails on build with error "java: cannot find symbol symbol:   variable log"

There is no error displayed in java class, annotation @Slf4j is used which is imported from "lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;"

Mvn clean Compile job is finished with success status.

I'm using Intellij Idea v2020.2.3 with Lombok plugin 0.32-2020.2 and Java 8.

checked:

- "Enable annotation processing" checkbox is active
- For Lombok plugin all checkboxes are active
  [image]
- I have read topic: [Building with Lombok's @Slf4j and Intellij: Cannot find symbol log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866765/building-with-lomboks-slf4j-and-intellij-cannot-find-symbol-log)
- And this: [Can't compile project when I'm using Lombok under IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424364/cant-compile-project-when-im-using-lombok-under-intellij-idea)
- And I have tried this: [[BUG] Maven: Java modules wont' build without explicit](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/2325)

After downgrade back to 4.8.0 building is back to success.

**dependencies:**

<cucumber.version>6.8.0</cucumber.version>

```
dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.14</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-alpha1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-alpha1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
    <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
    <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
    <version>15.0.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
    <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Can you compare what is the difference of `mvn dependency:tree` between both versions of Cucumber dependencies?

Comment: Also can you try `File > Invalidate Caches ...` to nuke everything up and see if it helps

Comment: Does it build in the command line via Maven?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki 
https://imgur.com/lycrMbn
https://imgur.com/6ursfRn
https://imgur.com/jl6QfFm

Comment: @CrazyCoder
yes, finished with success status.

Comment: Did you try to delete .idea directory and reimport the project from pom.xml? If it doesn't help, please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the sample project to reproduce attached.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki
Invalidate caches wont help

Comment: @CrazyCoder
>Did you try to delete .idea directory and reimport the project from pom.xml?
nope, doesn't help, so you think this is a bug? what do you mean attach the sample of project?

Comment: See [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).